# Segmentation Fault (SIGSEGV) in Geeks for Geeks problem

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, pointers

Hi there I was trying to solve a problem on Geeks for Geeks using brute for approach, so the problem statement was,

Given an array of positive integers. Your task is to find the leaders in the array.
Note: An element of array is leader if it is greater than or equal to all the elements to its right side. Also, the rightmost element is always a leader.

Input:
The first line of input contains an integer T denoting the number of test cases. The description of T test cases follows.
The first line of each test case contains a single integer N denoting the size of array.
The second line contains N space-separated integers A1, A2, ..., AN denoting the elements of the array.

Output:
Print all the leaders.

```
Constraints:
1 <= T <= 100,
1 <= N <= 107,
0 <= Ai <= 107

Example:
Input:
3
6
16 17 4 3 5 2
5
1 2 3 4 0
5
7 4 5 7 3
Output:
17 5 2
4 0
7 7 3
```

I developed my solution as below,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

long **leader;
long *cond; 

void leader_in_array(long *A,long N,long i) {
    long check = 0, count = 0;
    for (long j = N - 1; j >= 0 ; j--)
    {
        if (check <= A[j])
        {
            check = A[j];
            leader[i][count] = check;

            count++;
        }   
    }   

    cond[i] = count;
}

int main() {
    long T;

    cin >> T;

    leader = new long*[T];
    cond = new long(T);

    for (long i = 0; i < T; i++)
    {
        long N;
        cin >> N;
        long *A = new long(N);
        leader[i] = new long[N];

        for (long j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            cin >> A[j];
        }

        leader_in_array(A, N, i);

        delete [] A;

    }

    for (long i = 0; i < T; i++)
    {
        
        for (long j = cond[i] - 1; j >=0 ; j--)
        {
            cout << leader[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        
    }

    delete [] leader;
    delete [] cond;
    
    return 0;
}
```

It works with test cases but when I try to submit my code during actual cases I am getting error as

**Segmentation Fault (SIGSEGV)**

I understand what it is but not able to identify where am i doing it wrong.

Comment: You mean you are solving [Leaders in an array | Practice | GeeksforGeeks](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/leaders-in-an-array/0)?

Comment: `int N, A[10];` What if `N > 10`?

Comment: Read [a good C++ programming book](https://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html), then [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp), then documentation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and of [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your updated code it looks like you have a typo at  `long *A = new long(N);` I believe you want  `long *A = new long[N];`

Regardless, you are over complicating things. First, use `std::vector` to eliminate all the memory allocation stuff. Second, process each test case fully - that is, don't save the printing until all the test cases are complete. Run a test case and print the results of that test case. Repeat.

Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
 
int main() {
    uint32_t T;
    std::cin >> T;
    while (T--) {
        uint32_t N;
        std::cin >> N;
        // Create input vector and read data
        // The parameter tells the vector the initial size
        std::vector<uint32_t> data(N);
        for (auto i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            std::cin >> data[i];
        }
        // max is the maximum value at each iteration of the loop
        // Initialized to the last value of the array
        uint32_t max = data.back();
        std::vector<uint32_t> results;
        // Move backwards through the input (i.e. right to left)
        for (auto it = data.rbegin(); it != data.rend(); it++) {
            // If current value is > any value to the right
            if (*it >= max) {
                results.push_back(*it);
                max = *it;
            }
        }
        // Print in reverse order before moving on to next test case
        for (auto it = results.rbegin(); it != results.rend(); it++) {
            std::cout << *it << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note: if there is no requirement to print the results in a certain order, you can eliminate the `results` vector and just print a number when found.

Also, you could just create the vectors once before the main loop, resizing them as needed. Not sure how much execution time this would save.

Comment: Yes I did it, but instead of using vector I did it using stack I am updating my answer thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The problem says `N` is upto 10**7 (10,000,000), but you are allocating only 10 elements for `A` and elements of `leader`. You must allocate enough elements.

To realize this, there are few points:

- The array `A` is allocated on the stack. In some environments the stack is limited to a few MB, so it should be marked as `static` to get it off from the stack.
- Simply changing `int leader[100][10];` to `int leader[100][10000000];` will result in telling them allocate too much memory. To avoid this, you should allocate for only one query and answer each query just after reading them instead of holding answers for all queries.

Comment: ```/tmp/ccPXXg8a.o: In function `leader_in_array(int*, int, int)':
beabd28accf1485b585ae542d1f8d997.cpp:(.text+0x93): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against symbol `cond_count' defined in .bss section in /tmp/ccPXXg8a.o
/tmp/ccPXXg8a.o: In function `main':
beabd28accf1485b585ae542d1f8d997.cpp:(.text+0x18d): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against symbol `cond_count' defined in .bss section in /tmp/ccPXXg8a.o
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status```

Comment: @DanielLangr Thank you for notifying. I rewrote my answer.

Comment: well As you said I should answer for each query separately and not storing the answers, but as you can see the problem statement I need to  take all input first and then only I show the output for all queries, so I think I need to store them

Comment: Shall I use dynamic arrays instead ?

Comment: @50_Seconds_Of_Coding I don't see that we need to take all input first. Using dynamic arrays should be OK, but will require more care than static arrays.

Comment: well i edited my answer with dynamic array but I guess I am still missing something

Answer (score 2):

The bug has been pointed out to you, but it's not worth fixing it. Your attempt is too complicated than it needs to be, and there seems to be a much simpler, trivial solution: one loop, search the array ***in reverse order***, and simply keep track each time a value is found that's higher than the highest value seen to date. That's it.

The problem specifies that the values are positive, so we can simply initialize the low watermark to 0, and run with it.

```
void all_leaders_in_array(int *arr, size_t size)
{
    int highest=0;

    while (size > 0)
    {
        if (arr[--size] > highest)
        {
              // arr[size] is a "leader" value here,
              // do whatever you want with it, print it, etc...

              highest=arr[size];
        }
    }
}
```

That's it. The above will find all so-called "leaders" in the array, using one, simple loop, without any complicated logic. By definition, this grabs all values in the array that are higher than all the following values. The solution becomes much simpler when the array is searched ***backwards***. Just keep track of the highest value seen, in the backwards order, and call it a day.

I can't find anything in the question that states whether the leader values must be shown in their original order. The above code will find/print the values in reverse order. If they must be reported in their original order of appearance, just save each value in a separate array, and then print ***that*** array, afterwards, in reverse order. Mission accomplished.

Comment: Hi there thank you for reply as I can see your logic it is nothing different than what I implemented its just the loops which I used to apply same logic. Our main issue is storing input as well as output dynamically and efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

void leader_in_array(long *A,long N) {
    long check = 0;
    stack<long> leader;
    for (long j = N - 1; j >= 0 ; j--)
    {
        if (check <= A[j])
        {
            check = A[j];
            leader.push(check); 
        }   
    }   

    while (leader.empty() == false)
    {
        cout << leader.top() << " ";
        leader.pop();
    }
    
}

int main() {
    long T;

    cin >> T;

    for (long i = 0; i < T; i++)
    {
        long N;
        cin >> N;
        long A[N];

        for (long j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            cin >> A[j];
        }

        leader_in_array(A, N);
        cout << endl;

    }
    
    return 0;
}
```